# How to get only year from mixed string? (php)

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have string like this :

```
$str[] = "November 28th, 2014 | 0 - 9, 2014, Karthik Nallamuthu";<br/>
$str[] = "October 6th, 2015 | 0 - 9, 2015, D. Imman";<br/>
$str[] = "November 22nd, 2017 | 0 - 9, 2017";<br/>
$str[] = "December 18th, 2009 | 0 - 9";<br/>
$str[] = "December 18th, 2009 | 0 - 9";<br/>
$str[] = "October 30th, 2015 | 0 - 9, 2015, Sean Roldan";<br/>
$str[] = "December 18th, 2009 | 0 - 9";<br/>
$str[] = "November 25th, 2011 | 0 - 9, 2011 |";<br/>
```

I want to get only year value from this array - string please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) is one way to do it, assuming all your data is in the same format:

```
foreach ($str as $s) {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('F jS, Y+', $s);
    echo "year of '$s' is ". (int)$date->format('Y') . "\n";
}
```

Output for your data:

```
year of 'November 28th, 2014 | 0 - 9, 2014, Karthik Nallamuthu' is 2014
year of 'October 6th, 2015 | 0 - 9, 2015, D. Imman' is 2015
year of 'November 22nd, 2017 | 0 - 9, 2017' is 2017
year of 'December 18th, 2009 | 0 - 9' is 2009
year of 'December 18th, 2009 | 0 - 9' is 2009
year of 'October 30th, 2015 | 0 - 9, 2015, Sean Roldan' is 2015
year of 'December 18th, 2009 | 0 - 9' is 2009
year of 'November 25th, 2011 | 0 - 9, 2011 |' is 2011
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also used this way,**If the array format is same and in between two delimiter or string**,

```
 foreach ($str as $key => $row) {
    echo "year of '$row' is <b>".extract_unit($row,",","|") . " <b></br>";
 }
 function extract_unit($string, $start, $end)
 {
  $pos = stripos($string, $start);

  $str = substr($string, $pos);

  $str_two = substr($str, strlen($start));

  $second_pos = stripos($str_two, $end);

  $str_three = substr($str_two, 0, $second_pos);

  $unit = trim($str_three); // remove whitespaces

  return $unit;
 }
```